# Special line break handling of periods in browsers?

Tags: html, line-breaks

I was testing a new EPUB reader today when I noticed something strange. If there are ellipsis in the text that are rendered as `. . .`, the reader was treating those periods as one unit, even though there are spaces between them. So I fired up Chrome to open up the underlying HTML document, and I found that Chrome has the same behavior, as well as iBooks and Readium.

I can't seem to find this documented anywhere -- is there special treatment of periods in browsers? I would have assumed that space is always a delimiter for when line breaks happen, but this seems to disprove that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

HTML user agents may have special treatment of periods (and other characters) in line breaking. This is not defined in specifications. In particular, HTML (or CSS) specifications do *not* require or recommend that [Unicode line breaking rules](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/unicode/linebr.html) be applied. However, parts of these rules have been implemented, to a varying degree, in browsers, causing [confusion](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html) both due to browser differences and because the rules are not suitable for all occasions.

In particular, the period “.”, or U+002E FULL STOP to be formal, has line breaking class IS (Infix Separator) in the Unicode rules ([UAX #14](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/)). As a verbal note says, “When not used in a numeric context, infix separators are sentence-ending punctuation. Therefore they always prevent breaks before.” Formally this is specified in rule LB13. This means that “. . .” is kept together, and no line break is allowed before the first period either (unless allowed or forced by higher-priority rules).

However, as far as I can see, this has not been implemented in web browsers in general (tested on Chrome, Firefox, IE on Win 7), so there might be something special in your document or context, or you might be using a different version of Chrome.

The rule about not breaking before a period has been *partly* implemented in IE. If you have, say, “foo .bar”, with a normal space before the period, IE won’t break the expression.

Comment: Hm, is there a CSS property that will prevent line breaks on ". . ." though? I looked but couldn't find any.

Comment: @WaynnLue, only in the sense that if you wrap the characters in an element (normally `span`), you can set `white-space: nowrap` on it.